# How to log Computer Environment name in log4net?

Tags: c#, logging

Does anyone know how to dump environment name in log4net?

e.g.

```
<conversionPattern value="%date{ISO8601} Server:%property{log4net:HostName} [%-5level] %m" />
```

This will give computer name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean by "environment name", but with [log4net contexts](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html) you can log anything: logged on user, ip address if dynamic etc.

Not sure how to add it to the e-mail subject, but in the body pattern would be:

```
<conversionPattern value="%date{ISO8601} Server:%property{environment} [%-5level] %m" />
```

after you init log4net, call this:

```
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["environment"] =
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables("EnvironmentName")+"AppName";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can just add $(COMPUTERNAME) to your conversionPattern. If it is the computername you were looking for?